# Ice connection failed message on Firefox but works on Chrome

Tags: node.js, webrtc

I have a webRTC project that i can make work on my local machine (nodeJS + firefox/chrome). When I try to deploy it under Amazon cloud, I have an issue in firefug : "Ice Connection Failed" (works fine on chrome)

Here is the SDP received from the server :

```
v=0
o=- 1613416276519675431 2 IN IP4 127.0.0.1
s=-
t=0 0
a=sendrecv
a=group:BUNDLE sdparta_0
a=msid-semantic:WMS
m=video 50830 UDP/TLS/RTP/SAVPF 120 121
c=IN IP4 172.19.0.4
a=candidate:3317750581 1 udp 2122260223 172.19.0.4 50830 typ host generation 0 network-id 1 network-cost 50
a=candidate:3317750581 1 udp 2122260223 172.19.0.4 50830 typ host generation 0 ufrag aByY network-id 1 network-cost 50
a=candidate:652303833 1 udp 1686052607 18.196.192.26 62055 typ srflx raddr 172.19.0.4 rport 50830 generation 0 ufrag aByY network-id 1 network-cost 50
a=candidate:2367567423 1 udp 41885439 172.19.0.3 64097 typ relay raddr 18.196.192.26 rport 62055 generation 0 ufrag aByY network-id 1 network-cost 50
a=candidate:2336434117 1 tcp 1518280447 172.19.0.4 47162 typ host tcptype passive generation 0 ufrag aByY network-id 1 network-cost 50
a=recvonly
a=extmap:5 urn:ietf:params:rtp-hdrext:toffset
a=extmap:4 http://www.webrtc.org/experiments/rtp-hdrext/abs-send-time
a=fingerprint:sha-256 D7:1F:45:72:1D:CF:93:C5:39:1A:1E:EF:11:5C:50:2A:77:5D:46:B5:63:8B:9D:A8:9C:60:8E:ED:5E:4A:AE:FD
a=ice-options:trickle
a=ice-pwd:Pl6x4NQYDFLspg6WsFJiRGj8
a=ice-ufrag:aByY
a=mid:sdparta_0
a=rtcp:9 IN IP4 0.0.0.0
a=rtcp-fb:120 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack
a=rtcp-fb:120 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:120 goog-remb
a=rtcp-fb:121 ccm fir
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack
a=rtcp-fb:121 nack pli
a=rtcp-fb:121 goog-remb
a=rtcp-mux
a=rtpmap:120 VP8/90000
a=rtpmap:121 VP9/90000
a=setup:active
```

Logs from about:webrtc :

```
(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1539156510689000 (id=8589934603 url=https://siteperso/):default)/STREAM(0-1539156510689000 (id=8589934603 url=https://siteperso/) aLevel=0)/COMP(1): All pairs are failed, and grace period has elapsed. Marking component as failed.

(ice/INFO) ICE-PEER(PC:1539156510689000 (id=8589934603 url=https://siteperso/):default): all checks completed success=0 fail=1

(generic/ERR) Error from TCPSocketChild: type: ConnectionRefusedError, name: Network

(turn/INFO) TURN(relay(IP4:192.168.44.17:64764/UDP|IP4:52.28.148.27:3478/UDP)): deallocating
```

When i test on local, i have this extra tag :

```
a=fmtp:126 profile-level-id=42e01f;level-asymmetry-allowed=1;packetization-mode=1
```

Maybe an issue because this tag is not present?

Update :

I have tried to use google/other stun/turn but the behavior didn't change
Here is the logs from chrome and firefox coturn

```
// chrome working


140: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 172.18.0.2:3478, remote addr 10.126.240.227:55194
140: session 129000000000000001: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
140: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 172.18.0.2:3478, remote addr 10.126.229.172:52614
140: session 129000000000000002: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
140: session 129000000000000001: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised
140: IPv4. Local relay addr: 172.18.0.2:59273
140: session 129000000000000001: new, realm=<webrtc>, username=<mph>, lifetime=600
140: session 129000000000000001: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
140: session 129000000000000001: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
140: session 129000000000000001: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
140: session 129000000000000002: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised
140: IPv4. Local relay addr: 172.18.0.2:60174
140: session 129000000000000002: new, realm=<webrtc>, username=<mph>, lifetime=600
140: session 129000000000000002: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
140: session 129000000000000002: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
140: session 129000000000000002: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
140: session 129000000000000001: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
140: session 129000000000000002: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet CREATE_PERMISSION processed, success
145: session 129000000000000002: refreshed, realm=<webrtc>, username=<mph>, lifetime=0
145: session 129000000000000002: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
146: session 129000000000000002: closed (2nd stage), user <mph> realm <webrtc> origin <>, local 172.18.0.2:3478, remote 10.126.229.172:52614, reason: allocation timeout
146: session 129000000000000002: delete: realm=<webrtc>, username=<mph>
147: session 129000000000000001: refreshed, realm=<webrtc>, username=<mph>, lifetime=0
147: session 129000000000000001: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet REFRESH processed, success
148: session 129000000000000001: closed (2nd stage), user <mph> realm <webrtc> origin <>, local 172.18.0.2:3478, remote 10.126.240.227:55194, reason: allocation timeout
148: session 129000000000000001: delete: realm=<webrtc>, username=<mph>


//firefox

355: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 172.18.0.2:3478, remote addr 10.126.229.172:45338
355: session 129000000000000003: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
355: session 129000000000000003: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised
355: IPv4. Local relay addr: 172.18.0.2:65030
355: session 129000000000000003: new, realm=<webrtc>, username=<mph>, lifetime=600
355: session 129000000000000003: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
356: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 172.18.0.2:3478, remote addr 10.126.240.227:61693
356: session 129000000000000004: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
356: session 129000000000000004: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised
356: IPv4. Local relay addr: 172.18.0.2:52732
356: session 129000000000000004: new, realm=<webrtc>, username=<mph>, lifetime=3600
356: session 129000000000000004: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success
356: handle_udp_packet: New UDP endpoint: local addr 172.18.0.2:3478, remote addr 10.126.240.227:61694
356: session 129000000000000005: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
356: session 129000000000000005: realm <webrtc> user <>: incoming packet message processed, error 401: Unauthorised
356: IPv4. Local relay addr: 172.18.0.2:61007
356: session 129000000000000005: new, realm=<webrtc>, username=<mph>, lifetime=3600
356: session 129000000000000005: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet ALLOCATE processed, success

365: session 129000000000000003: realm <webrtc> user <mph>: incoming packet BINDING processed, success
```

Comment: I have removed the H264 codec to match exactly the same SDP from my amazon bench but it works fine on my local environement

Answer (score 0):

Did you provide any ice-servers during PeerConnection object creation? If you didn't provide I'd suggest you do that. It works in your local machine because they're in same network. But it won't work in production(AWS) because they're in different networks and it can't do the NAT traversal by itself.

If you want to add ice servers [Read this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/RTCIceServer/urls)

There are few [free STUN servers](https://gist.github.com/mondain/b0ec1cf5f60ae726202e)

For more information on ice servers [Read this](https://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webrtc/infrastructure/)

If you need TURN servers then you can use some service providers like Xirsys or make your own turn server using CoTURN.

Comment: Since chrome works well on my AWS bench, i didn't check the STUN/TURN server. I use my own coturn deployed under AWS, I'm gonna check and come back here